# DatabaseCleaner cleans test and development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, database-cleaner

Why does this configuration seem to clean both my `test` and my `development` databases? It's pretty annoying to have to reseed `development` every time I run `rspec`.

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
```

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: m_development
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: booltox
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: m_test
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: booltox
  password:
```

Comment: Can you show us your ``database.yml``?

Comment: My bet is you have the same database configuration for ``test`` and ``development`` in your ``database.yml``. If so, define different databases for the two environments.

Comment: Another possible cause is that you have ``RAILS_ENV='develop'`` in you ``spec_helper.rb``

Comment: @dgilperez Yeah, that line isn't in my spec_helper either. Or test.rb.

Comment: I'd suggest you alter your database.yml file so that the development configuration is no longer valid (e.g. bad username, bad password, bad database name or non-existent entry.). If you are indeed accessing the development database during your test, you should see an exception that should let you diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Hi @CD-RUM, did you finally managed to solve this or find the cause? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did! Forgot about this thread. I'll post my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty foolish of me but this might help someone else. Don't forget to define your environment in your `spec_helper.rb` (thanks @dgilperez):

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
```